# function scope error in React. Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and javascript so please bear with me

I am building a basic todolist app

Main App.js is the following

```
  class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchTasks = this.fetchTasks.bind(this)
    this.strikeUnstrike = this.strikeUnstrike.bind(this) 
  };

  state = {
    todoList: [],
    activeItem: {
      id: null,
      title: '',
      completed: false,
    },
    editing: false,
  }

  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchTasks()
  }

  // pull the list of tasks from the API 
  fetchTasks() {  
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list/')
    .then( response => {
            this.setState({ todoList: response.data })
    } )
  } 
  
  strikeUnstrike(task) {
    task.completed = !task.completed
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-update/${task.id}/`
    let data  = {'completed': task.completed, 'title':task.title}
    axios.post( url, data)
      .then(response => this.fetchTasks() )
  }
  

  render() {
   

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div id ='task-container'>
          
          <TaskList
            tasks = {this.state.todoList}
            taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike(task)}
            // taptask = {() => this.strikeUnstrike(task)} // also tried this
          />    
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

My TaskList.js component looks like the following

```
import React from 'react';

const tasklist = (props) => {
        return (
            <div id='list-wrapper'>
                {props.tasks.map((task, index) => {
                    // console.log('the task X is :', task) // works
                    // console.log('the passed prop is :', props.taptask) //works
                return (
                    <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                    
                    
                    <div onClick={props.taptask(task)} style={{flex:7}} >
                        
                        { task.completed == false ? (
                        <span>{task.title}</span>
                        ) : (
                        <strike>{task.title}</strike>)}
                        
                    </div>

                    <div style={{flex:1}}>
                        <button 
                        //   onClick={ props.editClick(task)} 
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Edit</button>
                        {console.log('working')}
                        
                    </div>

                    <div style={{flex:1}}>
                        <button 
                        //   onClick = {props.deleteClick(task)}
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark">-</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    
}


export default tasklist;
```

Yet, I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined
App.strikeUnstrike
src/frontend/src/App.js:134
  131 | // this basically allows you to check off an item as complete by clicking on it 
  132 | // strikeUnstrike = (task) => {
  133 | strikeUnstrike(task) {
> 134 |   task.completed = !task.completed
      | ^  135 |   console.log('TASK :' , task.completed)
  136 | 
  137 |   let csrfoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken')
View compiled
taptask
src/frontend/src/App.js:166
  163 | 
  164 | <TaskList
  165 |   tasks = {this.state.todoList}
> 166 |   taptask = {() => this.strikeUnstrike()}
      | ^  167 |   // taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike(task)}
  168 |   // editClick = {()=> this.startEdit(task)}
  169 |   // deleteClick = {()=> this.deleteItem(task)}
View compiled
(anonymous function)
src/frontend/src/Components/TaskList/TaskList.js:15
  12 | <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
  13 | 
  14 | 
> 15 | <div onClick={props.taptask(task)} style={{flex:7}} >
     | ^  16 |     
  17 |     { task.completed == false ? (
  18 |     <span>{task.title}</span>
View compiled
```

I am aware of bindings and I've tried several approaches (using this.functionName.bind(this) in the constructor and the arrow function approach) however I'm not able to resolve the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option you are invoking a function before hand. Second option you are passing a function that uses a `task` variable that it doesn't exist.

you are passing down a function to `TaskList`, for that you should pass the function directly, or define it as arrow function you should define the `task` parameter:

```
      <TaskList
        tasks = {this.state.todoList}
        taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike} // this is better
        taptask = {(task) => this.strikeUnstrike(task)} // this also works
      />
```

**Edit**
as @Nadia Chibrikova points at your `TaskList` you should also fix your onClick correctly:

```
onClick={() => props.taptask(task)}
```

Comment: I'd add `onClick={props.taptask(task)}` should be `onClick={() =>props.taptask(task)}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, that your `task` is `undefined`.
So you could check for `undefined` and handle it properly, that would prevent the dirty error.

```
  133 | strikeUnstrike(task) {
> 134 |   task.completed = task && !task.completed
```

Then let's find out why `task` is `undefined`

```
 <TaskList
        ...
/** this will not work, because the function is executed 
immediately instead of beeing passed down as props. **/
  taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike(task)} 
//instead use this
  taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike}
//or this
  taptask = {(task) => this.strikeUnstrike(task)} // pay attention to task, which is passed down to strikeUnstrike()
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line:

```
    taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike(task)}
```

to this:

```
    taptask = {this.strikeUnstrike}
```

You need to give function reference, you don't need to call it.